# lodestone не хочет работать

Tags: python

Скопировал базовую настройку бота

```
import lodestone


bot = lodestone.createBot(
    host='sasha3131.aternos.me',
    port=20081,
    username='Bot'
)
```

и она не работает, выдает такую ошибку:
`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'prismarine-viewer' imported from C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\javascript\js\deps.js`
в консоль уже писал npm install prismarine-viewer оно скачалось  но все равно не работает

```
PS C:\NeWindows\Scripts\pythin\minecraftmicro> npm install prismarine-viewer

up to date, audited 137 packages in 1s

13 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```